# D3 treemap for very large dataset

Tags: javascript, ajax, css, d3.js

I am not sure if there is a way to implement this feature. I am looking in for something like zoomable treemaps but to load a few child levels on first go, then no node click add more child nodes and append them to the tree.

Say in http://bost.ocks.org/mike/treemap/ after i reach the leaf node, I make an ajax call if child exists, and if it does, I add them as a child to the graph. I dont want to redraw the graph from scratch, but rather make it more of a visualication on click. This is challenging to me, as i am not aware of how will the accumulate function will work.
This would ensure also, that if i click on grandparent it will help to go back to the previous parent.
This I am planning to achive:
1. Load on click
2. Make it more dynamic
3. Implement it for a very large dataset within browsers cache-able range though

Could someone please suggest something on this front?

Comment: what is very large? how many entries are we talking here?

Answer (score 0):

I would move the algorithm of calculating the dx, dy, x and y on the server side by accepting the size of the div where you would want to place the treemap on and on a single call I'd return objects upto depth 3 or 4. The challenge could be with the animation transition.